# How to add a string prefix to non-missing dataframe values?

Tags: python, pandas

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(age=[5, 6, np.NaN], born=[pd.NaT, pd.Timestamp('1939-05-27'), pd.Timestamp('1940-04-25')], name=['Alfred', 'Batman', ''], toy=[None, 'Batmobile', 'Joker']))
```

I can detect non-missing values:

```
df.notna()
```

Let's say I want to add '+' as the string prefix to all non-missing values:

```
    age         born     name         toy
0  +5.0          NaT  +Alfred        None
1  +6.0  +1939-05-27  +Batman  +Batmobile
2   NaN  +1940-04-25        +      +Joker
```

How can I use the returned boolean (dataframe) values to add a string prefix to every non-missing value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
df.mask(df.notna(), '+'+df.astype(str))
```

output:

```
    age         born     name         toy
0  +5.0          NaT  +Alfred        None
1  +6.0  +1939-05-27  +Batman  +Batmobile
2   NaN  +1940-04-25        +      +Joker
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `.applymap():`

```
df.applymap(lambda x: '+' + str(x) if pd.notna(x) else x)
```

Output:

```
     age          born     name         toy
0   +5.0           NaT  +Alfred        None
1   +6.0   +1939-05-27  +Batman  +Batmobile
2    NaN   +1940-04-25        +      +Joker
```